# Writing to 'unclosed' dvd-r

Tags: windows, dvd

I have two ISOs that I merged in one, the problem I have is creating the autorun file. I have read that if I burn one iso in a DVD-R and not 'close' the disk, and burn the second to it, it would make the disk appear as multiple volumes. Does this mean I can put two autorun files in one disk and have them work separately?

Comment: You're trying to make both ISO's bootable from one disk? From my understanding a DVD-R is write once also, so you can't modify the disk once it has been written to. It's also my understanding that if you want to write multiple times to a disk then the medium (the disk) has to be a DVD-RW type.

Comment: I just found this for you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD_recordable#DVD.2BR_and_DVD.2BRW_.28DVD_.22plus.22.29 explains R, RW